# Does android store local file system metadata in a database that I can query?

Tags: android

Does android monitor the local file system and store the metadata in a database that I can query?

I'm looking for something like the `MediaStore` where media metadata is indexed and stored in a database.

The reason I'm looking for this is that I'm writing a file manager app and it's kind of expensive for me to create a new `File` object and do a `listFiles()` each time I change directories.

Answer (score 0):

> Does android monitor the local file system

Yes, at least on Android 3.x and higher. This index is used for serving up files to Windows/OS X/Linux via MTP when a USB cable is attached.

> and store the metadata in a database that I can query?

Other than what you can get at from `MediaStore`, no, sorry, at least not at this time. Moreover, it probably would not help -- your `listFiles()` is probably faster than would be a cross-process `ContentProvider` query.